# Duration of defensive pacts in late game

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

My English civilisation is close friends with the Dutch and we've had a succession of defensive pacts to hold off the Carthaginians, Japanese, Americans, and Portuguese. I have G&K and BNW installed.

However, as the game progresses into the closing stages (1965 / turn 385), I've received notifications that our defensive pact has expired after only a few turns (varying from one turn to eight) instead of the correct thirty turns.

At first I assumed it was a glitch and that I was receiving the notification in error, but I checked and the option to sign a new defensive pact was there amongst the trade options in the diplomacy dialogue and the pact was not listed in the Your Relationships window.

I am aware of the glitches in the diplomacy system in Civ V, but **is there some way I can resolve this issue of the defensive pacts ending so quickly?** I have tried to avoid a bloodthirsty reputation, so if my ally is attacked I'd rather not be seen as being belligerent by having to manually declare ware. I do believe (although I am not 100% certain) that the existence of the defensive pact reduces the likelihood of another civilisation actually declaring war against one of the parties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Defensive pact is automatically disbanded when the civilization you have it with declares war itself to anybody else. Your people don't like to have defensive pact with somebody such aggressive that he declares war to anybody else.

That is quite good thing otherwise, because you have free hands to help or not to help attacked civ or anything else.

Comment: OK, that does make sense. The Netherlands did declare war (and so did I), entirely separate from the defensive pact.